# Equivalent representations

Tags: representation-theory

I have a few questions in relation to the definition of equivalent representations. I am looking at the following problem:

Suppose $\pi : G \to GL(V)$ is a representation . For $g \in G$ define $\pi^g : G \to GL(V)$ by $\pi^g (h)=\pi (g^{-1}hg)$. Show that $\pi$ is equivalent to $\pi^g$.

My first question is in relation to the definition of equivalent representations, to which I am using Vinbergs book "linear representations of groups" (p.5). If $\pi$ and $\pi^g$ are equivalent then there should exist an isomorphism $\varphi: V \to V$ such that

$$\varphi \pi (h)  = \pi^g (h) \varphi  $$
For all $h \in G$

I believe I should define the $\varphi$ such that this is true and then show that it is an isomorphism, but I am not sure if $\varphi \pi (h)  = \pi^g (h) \varphi  $ is meant at $\varphi \cdot \pi (h)  = \pi^g (h) \cdot \varphi  $ or as composition such that I am to prove that $(\varphi \circ \pi (h)) (v)  = (\pi^g (h) \circ \varphi) (v)$ for all v in V and all h in G. But when I try doing this it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Composition of linear maps is the same as multiplying two matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set $\varphi:=\pi(g^{-1})$. Then we have
$$\varphi\,\pi(h)=\pi(g^{-1})\pi(h)=\pi(g^{-1}h)=\pi(g^{-1}hgg^{-1})=\pi(g^{-1}hg)\pi(g^{-1})=\pi^g(h)\,\varphi\,.$$
The operation is composition of functions, which is equivalent to matrix multiplication once a basis of $V$ is fixed.